# Is a configuration of clang QtC 4.7 checks per config file possible?

Tags: qt, clang, qt-creator

QtC 4.7 offers the inline CLANG code checks, as shown in the screenshots. I can configure those from `options/C++`. But I wonder if I can have a **config file** which I can commit (git) so everyone in the team is using the same checks.

Is that possible (e.g. similar to Artistic style where I can use a file or the config in QtC)?

The checks I mean:
[image: CLANG checks in QtC]

Configure in C++ options, can I do the same in a config file?
[image: QtC C++ options]

--- Edit ---

I could use the annotations like `[[clang::fallthrough]]` which silence the warning, but cause other issues like VS2017 "attribute not supported warnings" (we compile on 3 compilers).