# Using clang annotations in QtC without VS2017 warnings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, clang, qt-creator

I would like to use clang annotations like here in QtC.

```
- case CAircraftMatcherSetup::PickFirst:
+ [[clang::fallthrough]]; case CAircraftMatcherSetup::PickFirst:
```

This works, but generates a `C5030` VC2017 warning

```
foo.cpp:198: warning: C5030: attribute 'clang::fallthrough' is not recognized
```

What is the best way to get rid of these warnings? Sure, I could just surpress `C5030`, but is there a better way? Like adding these attributes to a list VC accepts or such.

Related: [Is a configuration of clang QtC 4.7 checks per config file possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619853/is-a-configuration-of-clang-qtc-4-7-checks-per-config-file-possible)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I tried embedding it as a comment and that didn't work.

Comment: I am afraid I did not, but if so, I'll post it here

Comment: In this particular case, `[[clang::fallthrough]]` is not needed. The C++17 standard now defines a standard attribute `[[fallthrough]]`, which is accepted by VS2017 as well.